# Scrollstopping parallax effect not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, parallax

[My site](http://jvlook.nl) has a stop-scrolling parallax effect. The code I use to stop the scrolling is:

```
if ( parseInt($("div#bg").css("top"), 10) <= -0 ) {
    $('#content').css('top', (-0) + 'px');
    $('#logo').css('margin-top', (-142) + 'px');
}
```

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Opera but not so much in Safari. Is there a different code to use in Safari? I know Safari has a bug when it comes to scrolling, but I couldn't quite find an answer for it. Is there a workaround to make it also work in Safari? Or some kind of editor that I can run my code through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: you have some problem in the layout, since I'm not even seeing your works gallery on Safari. I see indeed, that all your gallery elements are individual element inside the main div, without a container, which can results in a very hard situation to control.

Back on topic

```
parseInt($("div#bg").css("top"), 10)
```

return NaN, which I suppose could be your problem. The top value of #bg is set to "auto", so parseInt() will return NaN since the first (and all the other characters :D) are CHAR instead of a number.

The code is working on Chrome because its javascript engine is a little bit more elastic, but it shouldn't actually works there, nor in the others browsers.

Suggestion:
Have you seen Skrollr? It's an open source jquery library for parallax effects. It's really well written and it looks it could really do your day here.

http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

Comment: That helped me clear a lot up, thanks. I tried giving the bg div a top, but that didn't work. I changed the elements that scroll with bg to scroll with the document instead. if  ($(document).scrollTop() >= 0) { $('#content').css('top', (-0) + 'px'); $('#logo').css('margin-top', (-142) + 'px'); }  Unfortunately, because this activates every time I scroll, the site keeps flickering. Do you know of a way to make the site only check at key moments, or in a more static way? Also Skrollr looks great, but ironically, won't run for me in Safari.

Comment: I didn't see your answer... There are a lot of ways. The best thing to do is to 'atomize' your problem. Divide it in little actions, take a look at the console and find the solution as I've showed you.
I don't know any other solution which work as good as skrollr, but surely google can be your friend, maybe with "scrolling parallax javascript library"